# Using map marker icon in KML download?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have a fusion table with a column that provides the map marker from one of the built-in options (e.g. large_red). I would like these same markers to be used when I do KML download of either type (static or dynamic, but especially dynamic). Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

We recently added styles to KML downloads, so if you download the static or network link KML your markers should appear. Have you tried this and found it not working as expected?

Comment: Yes, I have, and everything shows up as a yellow pushpin. Looking at the kml, I notice that there is no indication to the contrary; what's more, the column that should be named "icon" is in fact exported with an empty name: <Data name=""><value>large_blue</value></Data>

Comment: By the way, the kml network feed link is: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/exporttable?query=select+col4%3E%3E0+from+1JJHwwJLW1CqrG3PZv3kMBrRJio-5f_28g_rJrYU+where+col7%3E%3E0+%3D+'Y'&o=kmllink&g=col4%3E%3E0&styleId=2&templateId=3

Comment: Anyone? This is very puzzling. And I'd like to have my proper markers if possible.